# Get an NSDate for a following day of week from a reference NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Given a reference date I need to find the following say 'Wednesday'.

Just to be clear, if the reference date is say Tuesday then it should return the Wednesday from the **same** week.

If the reference date is Wednesday or later then it needs to return the following Wednesday from the **next** week.

It's important that it does not return a Wednesday past the reference date.

I've been looking at using `NSDateComponents` but not sure how to get the following day of the week that must always be in the future.

This is what I have so far:

```
NSDate *referenceDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:referenceDate];
[dateComponents setWeekday:4]; // Wednesday
NSDate *followingWednesday = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Though this code does not make the distinction between Wednesday past in the same week or the following Wednesday, and hear lies my problem.

I know I could generate two dates one from current week and one from the next week and then use an if statement to check which one is in the future but this seems like a lot of code to do a simple thing.

Is there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

It seems that setting the weekday does not actually affect the date returned by the `dateComponents:` method of NSCalendar. My example code above returns the same date regardless of what is set for the weekday.

So now I'm more stumped.

Comment: how about adding 7 days if the date is in the past, otherwise leave it alone?

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I'm doing but I'm interested to know if they is an nicer way of saying 'get me the next Wednesday' without having to write lots of extra logic. I'm hoping there is something I've missed with regards to the NSDateComponents class. There might not be and that fine, I'll just do it the way I already am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
NSDate *referenceDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:referenceDate];

int targetWeekday = 4;

if (dateComponents.weekday >= targetWeekday)
{
    dateComponents.week++;
}

dateComponents.weekday = targetWeekday;
NSDate *followingTargetDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Comment: did you add the `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` and `NSWeekCalendarUnit` flags when asking the calendar for the components? You might also have to remove the `NSDayCalendarUnit` flag. I can't test it right now.

Comment: Spot on, I had to remove `NSDayCalendarUnit`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through a NSDateFormatter. You could do something like this to calculate the next wednesay. I am not sure of what out you want, but here's an example:

```
NSDate *referenceDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *mincomp = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:referenceDate];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"e"];
while ([[formatter stringFromDate:[cal dateFromComponents:mincomp]] intValue] != 4)
    mincomp.day += 1;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"next wednesday = %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[cal dateFromComponents:mincomp]]);
```

Comment: This is interesting and does in fact work though it seems odd that you would have to rely on `NSDateFormatter` to do this though. Are there any caveats to using `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: As far as I know, no there is not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dateWithNaturalLanguageString`

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"next Wednesday"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

**Note** : `dateWithNaturalLanguageString`:

> Creates and returns an NSDate object set to the date and time specified by a given string.

```
+ (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string
```

**Parameters**

**string**

> A string that contains a colloquial specification of a date, such as “last Tuesday at dinner,” “3pm December 31, 2001,” “12/31/01,” or “31/12/01.”

Comment: Would love to use this, unfortunately this is only supported for MacOS X. Sorry should have made it clear that i'm using iOS 5. See tags.

Comment: Also you should consider that this works for who has english language as first in preferences, this case it's a good method for who uses os x.

Comment: I think it's a private API method so it's likely that Apple would reject use of it. I can't take that risk.

Comment: @Prince -- It's not documented under iOS.

Comment: @Prince -- "No known class selector for dateWithNaturalLanguageString"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the whole thing nicely tied up, because the implementation I coincidentally worked out yesterday is on a different computer, but roughly:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"e"];
NSInteger day = [[formatter stringFromDate:theDate] integerValue];
NSInteger offsetDays = (targetDay - day);  // targetDay is 4 for Wednesday
if (offsetDays < 0) offsetDays += 7;
NSDate* resultDate = [theDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:offsetDays * secondsInADay];
```

(The offsetDays calculation may be a bit haywire -- that sort of thing requires more thought than is available at this time in the morning.)

Comment: I'm not sure this solution would handle timezones and daylight saving time properly.

Comment: @Camsoft - The above should work fine regardless of timezone, since it offsets in even 24-hour increments.  (The formatter needs to be set to the TZ you're concerned about, to get the right day, of course.)  DST changes require separate effort, though.

Answer (score -1):

[This guy nailed it.](http://danroundhill.com/2011/05/16/how-to-get-an-nsdate-for-a-specific-day-of-week-and-time-from-an-existing-nsdate/)

Adapted for OP:

```
NSDate *refDate = [NSDate date]; // or whatever
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:refDate];
int wednesday = 4;
if(nowComponents.weekday >= wednesday) {
    [nowComponents setWeek: nowComponents.week + 1]; // Next week
}
[nowComponents setWeekday:wednesday]; // Wednesday
[nowComponents setHour:8]; // Specific time (if desired)
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];

NSDate *nextWednesday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```

As you stated, this will get the "next Wednesday" every time, even if reference date is a Wednesday.

**EDIT**: Fixed bug pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Let's say refDate is tuesday, and you use this code: you will get wednesday of 8 days in the future, not wednesday of 1 day in the future, which the OP asked for.

Comment: Bah. Good catch and silly me. Would need to conditionally increment the week, as @Tobi has done.